# delete data from db with jquery and ajax

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax

i have ta data from my db and i displayed it using datatable.. now what im trying to do is to delete a record but instead of a success return it gives an error.

```
  datatable.on('click','.delete-row',function(){
       tr = $(this).closest('tr'),
            data = datatable.row(tr).data();

        var result = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?')
        if(result){
        $.ajax({
          url:'../ajax/delete_users.php',
          dataType:'JSON',
          data: {id: data.users_id},

          success: function(result){
            console.log(result);
          },
          error: function(status){
            console.log(status.responseText);

          }
        });
      }
    });
```

here is my **delete.php**

```
if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
     $id = $_POST['id'];
     $data = $users->deleteUsers($id);
      echo json_encode($data);

}
```

the query is just  like this..

```
public function deleteUsers($id)
    {
        $sql = "DELETE FROM tbl_users WHERE users_id = '$id'";
        $update = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
        $update->execute();
        return $update->rowCount() ? true : false;
    }
```

Comment: Add the error message please

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: As has been said many times before, _please_ use a prepared statement here.  Someone could spoof your program now and cause _all_ users to be deleted via SQL injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not setting the method on your ajax request, so it is sent using GET but you try to read from POST. Try to add method: 'POST' to the request.

Also use a bind parameter for $id in your query. I can delete all users by sending in id = 1' or 1=1 as the user id

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function deleteUsers($id)
{
    $sql = "DELETE FROM tbl_users WHERE users_id = ".(int)$id;
    $update = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
    $update->execute();
    return $update->rowCount() ? true : false;
}
```